# Shutdown Windows from WSL

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, reboot

I searched for this, but all I got were reboots of WSL in WSL, but I want to shutdown or reboot my actual PC from a WSL session. Is this in any way possible?

I run Windows 10 & Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WSL can run Windows tools directly from the WSL command line using
the syntax of `[tool-name].exe`.

In WSL, to shutdown use the
[shutdown command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown).

For example, type the following command to gracefully shut down
after one minute:

```
shutdown.exe /s
```

For immediate shutdown, add the parameter `/t 0`.